# what is the jdbc connection string when using a docker container?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, spring-data-jpa

I am running a mysql docker container using:

> docker run -p33060:33060 --name some-mysql2 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest

and it works fine, I can access that container using `docker exec -it 055054ef4e56 bash` and add database ... etc

and this is the container:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                NAMES
ea1693f5cdc8   mysql:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 minutes ago   Up 18 minutes   3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33060->33060/tcp   some-mysql2
```

I want to connect to that mysql server from spring boot, so I want to know the connection string

I tried:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://some-mysql2:33060/MyDB
```

and

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/MyDB
```

but didn't work, I am getting `used by: java.net.UnknownHostException: some-mysql2` and if I use localhost, then I get

nsupported protocol version: 11. Likely connecting to an X Protocol port.

what is the correct connection string in case of a docker container?

Comment: 'Didn't work' is not a problem description.

Comment: @user207421 I added the error I am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost ok:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://some-mysql2:33060/MyDB
```

But the default port for Mysql is 3306, so I think that you have to run your container like so:

```
docker run -p 33060:3306 --name some-mysql2 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
```

Please take a look at this [example](https://dzone.com/articles/all-about-hibernate-manytomany-association)

Comment: I am getting used by: java.net.UnknownHostException: some-mysql2

Comment: and if I change it to localhost, I get nsupported protocol version: 11. Likely connecting to an X Protocol port.

Comment: Try to get inside the container using: *docker exec -it some-mysql2 bash*
Than try to log in to mysql: *mysql -u root -p* (provide your root's password).

Comment: @[Marco Dinatsoli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2038257/marco-dinatsoli):
have you solved your problem?
Thank you for accepting my answer, that's very kind of you,

Comment: yes I solved it, I changed the host to localhost and as what you said, port is 3306

Comment: Thanks for helping